# Obtener los dias de la semana a partir de una fecha - Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date

Cree una función en la cúal me trae los días de la semana de **Lunes a Domingo**:

```
    weekLabel(current) {
        const week = [];
        const weekFormat = [];
        current.setDate(((current.getDate() - current.getDay()) + 1));
        for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
          week.push(new Date(current));
          current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1);
        }
        week.forEach((w) => {
          weekFormat.push(moment(w).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
        });
        return weekFormat;
      },
```

En el cual **current** es lo que esta esperando la función que le pase en este caso una fecha... esto funciona correctamente pero cuando le paso una fecha de un domingo ya me devuelve los días de la otra semana. Se que la semana empieza desde el domingo pero quisiera saber si puedo poner que empiece desde el **Lunes**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que getDay() siempre te va a retornar 0 en el día Domingo, una solución puede ser incluir un If para que cuando llegue al día Domingo lo tomé como si fuera el Séptimo día de la semana. Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
function weekLabel(current) {
const week = [];
const weekFormat = [];

if(current.getDay() == 0){//En los casos en que es domingo, restar como si fuera septimo dia y no cero
    current.setDate(((current.getDate() - 7) + 1));
}else{
    current.setDate(((current.getDate() - current.getDay()) + 1));
}

for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    week.push(new Date(current));
    current.setDate(current.getDate()+1);
}
week.forEach((w) => {
    weekFormat.push(moment(w).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
});
return weekFormat;
```

}

Ya lo probé y dio resultados. Espero te sirva

Comment: Muy buena respuesta e idea. Muchas gracias Jose !